# Proving idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra

**Let A be an involution and let B=1/2(I+A),  C=1/2(I-A).
Show that B and C are both idempotent and BC=0.**

TO SEE WHAT I HAVE TRY Visit: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U9ISv-vfrWEszYB3HYrp1zmxxuXTNRs4cFIK3x_PbUg/edit?usp=sharing

It is right or I left something??

Comment: Where do $\;A,B,C\;$ live? A group? What group? You're a member almost 1 year, you should by now already know how to type mathematics in a nice way.

Comment: @Timbuc:  eniid15 can't be talking about a group, since his equations manifest two ring-like operations.  It seems to me, contextually, rings (including rings of operators) are in evidence.  As far as the $\LaTeX$ or lack thereof is concerned, right on!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis, the problem is I can't understand the equations (s)he wrote.\

Comment: @Timbuc:  Understood; I had to work to decipher them myself!

Comment: More precisely, a ring in which division by two is well defined :-).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  Hear, hear!  I didn't mention that since it seemed contextually clear that this is the case!

Answer (score 1):

With $A^2 = I$ (this seems to be what is meant by "$A$ is an involution" here), then with

$B = \dfrac{1}{2}(I + A) \tag{1}$

we have

$B^2 = \dfrac{1}{4}(I + A)^2 = \dfrac{1}{4}(I + 2A + A^2) = \dfrac{1}{4}(2I + 2A) = \dfrac{1}{2}(I + A) = B, \tag{2}$

so $B$ is idempotent.  So that part is OK.  However, as far as $C$ is concerned, there is an error in the OP's computation:

$(I - A)^2 = I - 2A + A^2 = 2I - 2A, \tag{3}$

***NOT***

$(I - A)^2 = I - 2A - A^2 = -2A, \tag{4}$

and ***CERTAINLY NOT***

$(I - A)^2 = I - 2I - A^2 = I - 2I - I = -2I \tag{5}$

(or something like that), as eniid15's remarks (which have since been replaced in the question by a link) suggested.  (2) and (3) follow by virtue of the fact that $I$ and $A$ commute, so as far as polynomials are concerned, the usual rules for polynomial arithmetic (remembering that $A^2 = I$) or arithmetic in $\Bbb R[x]/(x)$ etc. apply.  From (3),

$C^2 = \dfrac{1}{4}(2I - 2A) = \dfrac{1}{2}(I - A) = C, \tag{6}$

so $C$ is in fact idempotent.  Now since

$(I + A)(I - A) = I^2 - A^2 = I - I = 0, \tag{7}$

it follows that

$BC = \dfrac{1}{4}(I + A)(I - A) = 0; \tag{8}$

note we also have

$CB = 0. \tag{9}$

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Fiat Lux, indeed! At least my general experience with idempotents dictates that this is the only interpretation that makes sense :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  Indeed.  Let me say that once again:  indeed.  Now *there's* fifteen characters!